# How to execute external script in views.py in django application?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Following is my django file structure

- myproject
- myapp

  - migrations
  - static
  - templates

    - myapp

      - demo.html
  - urls.py
  - views.py
  - models.py
  - admin.py
  - apps.py
  - tests.py
- Scripts

  - demo_script.py
- manage.py

What I want to know is how to execute the script Scripts/demo_script.py (which is outside the application "myapp") from views.py and if it is executed successfully, show "Success" on myapp/templates/myapp/demo.html or else show "Failed to execute" on the same html page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

simply use:

```
relative_path = "scripts/demo_script.py"
# or
absolute_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "scripts", "demo_script.py")

exec(open(relative_path or absolute_path).read())  # execute the py file
```

All the paths referenced in Django are relative to the `BASE_DIR`. `BASE_DIR` is where your `manage.py` lies.